# How to find duplicate data during insertion in mysql ?

Tags: php, mysql, on-duplicate-key

I want to find duplicate data with this query which may occur during insertion. Is there any way to find it?

```
INSERT INTO table_tags (tag) VALUES ('tag_a'),('tab_b'),('tag_c')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tag=tag;
```

Comment: Assuming tag is a uniquely keyed column, SELECT tag FROM table_tags WHERE tag IN ('tag_a','tab_b','tag_c'), but does seem pointless. By the way you are missing VALUES from the update (probably irrelevant in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
INSERT INTO table_tags
   (tag)
VALUES
   (?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   tag     = VALUES('tag_a')
```

Note that, column `tag` should be `unique`